# RxJs debounce emits event immediately during jest tests

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, jestjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to write a test function to a redux-observable epic. The epic works fine inside the app and I can check that it correctly debounces the actions and waits 300ms before emitting. But for some reason while I'm trying to test it with jest the debounce operator triggers immediately. So my test case to ensure that the debounce is working fails.

This is the test case

```
it('shall not invoke the movies service neither dispatch stuff if the we invoke before 300ms', done => {
    const $action = ActionsObservable.of(moviesActions.loadMovies('rambo'));

    loadMoviesEpic($action).subscribe(actual => {
        throw new Error('Should not have been invoked');
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
        done();
    }, 200);

});
```

and this is the epic

```
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounce';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/concat';

import actionTypes from 'actions/actionTypes';
import * as moviesService from 'services/moviesService';
import * as moviesActions from 'actions/moviesActions';

const DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL_IN_MS = 300;
const MIN_MOVIES_SEARCH_LENGTH = 3;

export function loadMoviesEpic($action) {
  return $action
    .ofType(actionTypes.MOVIES.LOAD_MOVIES)
    .debounce(() => Observable.interval(DEBOUNCE_INTERVAL_IN_MS))
    .filter(({ payload }) => payload.length >= MIN_MOVIES_SEARCH_LENGTH)
    .switchMap(({ payload }) => {
      const loadingAction = Observable.of(moviesActions.loadingMovies());

      const moviesResultAction = Observable.from(
        moviesService.searchMovies(payload)
      )
        .map(moviesResultList => moviesActions.moviesLoaded(moviesResultList))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(moviesActions.loadError(err)));

      return Observable.concat(loadingAction, moviesResultAction);
    });
}

const rootEpic = combineEpics(loadMoviesEpic);

export default rootEpic;
```

I would like to avoid marble testing, what shall I do to make this work?

---

EDIT:

this is my spy definition.

```
    jest.mock('services/moviesService');

    const spy = jest.spyOn(moviesService, 'searchMovies');

    beforeEach(() => {
        moviesService.searchMovies.mockImplementation(keyword => {
            return Promise.resolve(moviesResult);
        });
        spy.mockClear();
    });
```

so basically this thing shall not be called, because the debounce time is 300ms and I'm trying to check the spy after 200ms. But after 10ms the spy is being invoked.

Comment: what is `spy` here? you might use mock to subscribe to the epic and test agains calls to this mock.

Comment: @Kos, I've originally omitted the spy definition, but I added it on the edit. Plus I don't want to mock the epic as it's implementation is exactly what I want to test. I'm mocking the services that it uses, but I want to make sure for example that it will not emit before 300 ms(among other things).